# Specifying the foreign keys in a belongsToMany-through association

Tags: cakephp, orm, foreign-keys, cakephp-3.0

I want to set the used foreign keys when using a belongsToMany-through association in CakePHP 3.0.

Consider the following two tables:

**entities**: id, title
**links**: id, from_id, to_id, additional_information

I am using a belongsToMany-through association because of the additional information I need to store in the through-table.

Here are the two Table classes:

```
class LinksTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->belongsTo('FromEntities', [
            'className' => 'Entity',
            'foreignKey' => 'from_id'
        ]);
        $this->belongsTo('ToEntities', [
            'className' => 'Entity',
            'foreignKey' => 'to_id'
        ]);
    }
}

class EntitiesTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->belongsToMany('Entities', [
            'through' => 'Links'
        ]);
    }
}
```

But of course CakePHP tries to join the tables using the default foreign key `entity_id`, which is not correct.

**How can I define the foreign keys used to join the tables in the EntitiesTable class?**

*Edit*: For completeness' sake, here are the error message and generated query when trying to fetch an Entity with association using `$this->Entities->findById(1)->contain('Entities');`.

> Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Links.entity_id' in 'field list'

```
SELECT Links.entity_id AS `Links__entity_id`, Links.id AS `Links__id`, Links.from_id AS `Links__from_id`, Links.to_id AS `Links__to_id`, Links.type AS `Links__type`, Links.role AS `Links__role`, Entities.id AS `Entities__id`, Entities.type AS `Entities__type`, Entities.title AS `Entities__title`, Entities.user_id AS `Entities__user_id`, Entities.created AS `Entities__created` FROM entities Entities INNER JOIN links Links ON Entities.id = (Links.entity_id) WHERE Links.entity_id in (:c0)
```

*There are some additional fields in the generated queries that I stripped out of the code examples above, in case you are wondering.*

Answer (score 1):

After digging through some test cases, I found the answer in [this test](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/master/tests/TestCase/ORM/CompositeKeysTest.php).

The method `belongsToMany` has an undocumented option `targetForeignKey`, so the EntitiesTable class should look like this:

```
class EntitiesTable extends AppTable
{
    public function initialize(array $config) {
        parent::initialize($config);

        $this->belongsToMany('LinkedEntities', [
            'className' => 'Entities',
            'through' => 'Links',
            'foreignKey' => 'from_id',
            'targetForeignKey' => 'to_id'
        ]);
    }
}
```

Now I am able to access the linked Entity using `$this->Entities->findById(1)->contain('LinkedEntities');`